# Starling embed bitmap reference error

Tags: runtime-error, starling-framework

I have the following code in the Game.as:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;

import starling.display.Image;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.textures.Texture;
import starling.utils.deg2rad;

public class Game extends Sprite
{
    private const NUM_SAUSAGES: uint = 400;

    private var sausagesVector: Vector.<Image> = new Vector.<Image>(NUM_SAUSAGES, true);

    [Embed(source = "../media/textures/sausage.png")]
    private static const Sausage: Class;

    public function Game()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
    }

    private function onAdded(e: Event): void
    {
        var sausageBitmap: Bitmap = new Sausage();

        var texture: Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(sausageBitmap);

        for (var i: int = 0; i < NUM_SAUSAGES; ++i)
        {
            var image: Image = new Image(texture);

            image.alpha = Math.random();

            image.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            image.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
            image.rotation = deg2rad(Math.random() * 360);

            addChild(image);

            sausagesVector[i] = image;
        }
    }
}
}
```

But when I run the code it gives me the following error:
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable Game_Sausage is not defined.

What is the problem with the code because I have no idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the notation but I would hazard a guess that:

```
private static const Sausage: Class;
```

is never assigned, but defined as const. The [Embed] might not be finding the file?

a quick google found:
http://www.flexer.info/2009/05/01/getdefinitionbyname-error-variable-is-not-defined/

which might or might not be relevant

Comment: If I add getDefinitionByName it bives me another error.:(

Comment: When googling there were a number of issues showing up wiht the error number, some were very vague (flash version) others like the suggestion I made, resource not found. are you sure the path of your embed is correct? are other resources loading correctly or could it be it needs to be textures/.../etc. ? instead of ../? Your source folder organisation might differ from the compiled/packaged artifacts as well.

Comment: so you have another class that uses an embed with ../ that does work?